Mass Transit DeadLetter with Azure Service Bus
I have used Mass Transit with rabbit mq and .NET 6 for a while and now for a different project, I am trying it with an Azure Service Bus.
I have read the documentation to a certain point and I understand the error queue from mass transit but I wish I could put a failed message with a fixable error or otherwise in the dead letter queue of my Azure Service Bus. I do not wish for mass transit to keep trying to create topics of my queues nor do I wish for my messages to go to a dlq only after the number of retries has been hit. I wish for my messages to keep the logs of the errors and if I want them in the dlq to be able to send them there.
For now, I can't send a message to a dlq nor can I add extra errors info in the custom props as the azure service bus operates. How do I fix it?
PS: I did add the exclude from topology tag to all my events but in my console I still see mass transit trying to create subs in my basic tier service bus. I want to be in control of my queues and my subs :(

Use of the basic tier, while it might be possible to figure out, is not officially supported by MassTransit.
